# How does the Reddit front page algorithm work so that it shows many different subreddits?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, sorting, ranking, reddit

You probably have noticed that on the front page, you don't see two posts of the same subreddit in a row, but rather a wide variety of different subreddits on the entire frontpage (if you have subscribed to enough subreddits of course). I wonder how they achieved that? I know how the [hot sorting algorithm](https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/how-reddit-ranking-algorithms-work-ef111e33d0d9) works, but I have no clue what it does to show this variety of different subreddits and posts with completely different amount of votes. It somehow has to account for subreddits that have less subscribers or a lower average amount of upvotes per post I guess?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I'm not sure if it's on topic here. Is the algorithm closed-source? Probably. Is this question too broad to be asked here? I'm not sure.

Comment: @byxor As far as I know, Reddit was completely open source not too long ago. So I thought someone might know how they do it or if experienced programmers would approach this in a different way?

Comment: This question does sound off-topic, but I like it. To make it _more_ on-topic, perhaps change it from "How does ____ work?" to "How can I reproduce ___?" and suggests a few things you've tried / thought about to demonstrate your research effort. Make it more of a practical problem rather than a theoretical one.